# Information Policy MAnagement

Tags: sharepoint-server, information-policy

Why am I getting this error:

> Error running the expiration action on item http://***.
>
> Error:  System.InvalidOperationException: The workflow with
> id=e64932fc-a9bf-4754-bd4f-e57601d6b3fc is no longer available.    at
> Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.PolicyFeatures.WorkflowExpirationAction.RunExpirationWithPostActions(SPListItem
> item, XmlNode parametersData, DateTime expireDate)    at
> Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.PolicyFeatures.BaseExpirationAction.Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.PolicyFeatures.IExpirationActionWithPostActions.OnExpirationWithPostActions(SPListItem
> item, XmlNode parametersData, DateTime expireDate)    at
> Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.PolicyFeatures.ExpirationTask.ExpirationActionData.RunExpirationAction(SPListItem
> item, DateTime expireDate)    at
> Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.PolicyFeatures.ExpirationTask.<>c__DisplayClass19.b__17(SPListItem
> item)    at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.MonitoredScopeWrapper.RunWithMonitoredScope(Action
> code)    at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.ContentIterator.ProcessItem(SPListItem
> item, Boolean fIncludeFolderItems, MonitoredScopeWrapper
> monitoredScopeWrapper, ItemProcessor itemProcessor,
> ItemProcessorErrorCallout errorCallout)

When in reality I have no rules/information policies activated on the site?

Answer (score 0):

As per the below thread if we publish the workflow globally it should work.

[Error running the expiration action and The workflow is no longer available](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/8fbf65d4-91bd-4de6-a7de-ca5d7062babb/error-running-the-expiration-action-and-the-workflow-is-no-longer-available?forum=sharepointgeneral)

Other similar thread (issue) to refer:

[SharePoint Retention Policy workflow does not start](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/e0a4523c-6a68-4a68-a3b2-b7433fdc746b/sharepoint-retention-policy-workflow-does-not-start?forum=sharepointgeneral)

**How to trace the workflow details by the GUID?**

Go to the workflow history list(hidden list), then find workflow details with the said GUID.

```
http://yourservername/yoursitename/Lists/Workflow%20History
```

Comment: However, I have no WF / Information policies set... that is why I have no idea where the error is coming from

Comment: any idea how i can find out which workflow it is referring to from the ID?

Comment: Please see the "How to trace the workflow details by the GUID?" section.

Comment: thnks - my workflow history is empty. any idea why I get the exception even though I have no information policies set ?